# Why does my 3d object move around even though I have good motion tracking

Tags: tracking, motion-capture

I've switched from native Blender motion tracking to using [April Tools](https://github.com/thegoodhen/AprilTools) mentioned in [CGMatter's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wrecO5twh4).

This seems to be working really well. However, I have a 3D model of a porsche that is giving me problems.

Admittedly, the footage is pretty shaky, but despite that, I can tell that the tracking is good:
[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnzEOEHjhMk) shows the problem. Note how the grey marker perfectly covers the black april tag square all through the video, yet the porsche still bounces around.

It doesn't seem to be a size or geometry issue either, since I don't have the problem when I use a large cube or when I use a small porsche. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Do you remember what the solve value was? If it's over 0.8 it might need some cleaning up still.

Comment: April Tools doesn't include a solve error, it tracks the footage through it's own python script and generates keyframes for camera/marker movement. To iterate: the tracking is good, as evidenced by the grey marker on the ground remaining perfectly in place. If the tracking was bad, you would see that marker move around like the porsche does, and you would see the black square tag that it's covering.

Comment: Maybe ask directly in the github page for aprilstools would be a better place for this.